# Rails: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my rails application I have this method in the job model that return the job of a company from job show page

```
  def same_company
    Job.approved.where(company: self.company).where.not(job: self.job)
  end
```

but this doesn't work and give me this error

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Why I'm getting this error? and how can I resolve this

Update

This the error that I found in my log file

```
Rendered jobs/show.html.erb within layouts/application (352.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1155ms

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
    154:       <div class="cl3_comp">
    155:         <div class="_3clmn_dictry">
    156:           <ul class="uList _3clmn _4direct">
    157:             <% @job.same_company(6).each do |same_company_job| %>
    158:               <li class="_lidiretry">
    159:                 <div class="clearfix _5qo4">
    160:                     <%= link_to job_path(same_company_job), class: "_5q6s _8o _8t lfloat _ohe" do %>
  app/models/job.rb:65:in `same_company'
  app/views/jobs/show.html.erb:157:in `_app_views_jobs_show_html_erb__849384532_94102470'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:59:in `show'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:61:in `user_time_zone'
```

This is my job model

```
 #company
    belongs_to :company

  #User
  belongs_to :user

  def same_company
    Job.approved.where(company: self.company).where.not(job: self.job)
  end
```

Comment: show the full error stack please

Comment: Which method call is raising the exception? (This may be easier to determine if you split that chain of calls into multiple statements)

Comment: This is the error that I'm getting wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) for    <% @same_company_jobs.each do |same_company_job| %>

Comment: The error means you're passing an argument to a method that shouldn't receive any arguments. Without a full stack trace we can't really help you.

Comment: Where can I find the full stack trace I'm a newbie and I have just copied the error that I have in the screen

Comment: in your rails server log... I hope you are running your server locally and from the console you have started the server using `rails s`, there you can see the error trace.

Comment: Please take a look at my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fix is :

```
<% @job.same_company[0...6].each do |same_company_job| %>
```

As per the method definition `same_company`, it don't accept any argument, but you are sending `same_company(6)`. I think you want first `6` rows, so  the above code is what you need.

Comment: No w I'm getting this error undefined method `job' for #<Job:0xbc7da70>

Comment: Show your `Job` model and the output of `Job.column_names`.

Comment: The trouble will be this part `not(job: self.job)`...`self` is the current job so there isn't a `self.job`... you could use either `not(job: self)` or `not(id: id)`

Comment: You can see my job model in the update The output Job.column_names always return the exact output

Comment: Not one of them has worked this one not(id: id) raise this error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass  and this not(job: self) raise this one PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column jobs.job does not exist

Comment: Now it work after updating my code from <% @job.same_company[.6].each do |same_company_job| %> to <% @job.same_company[0...6].each do |same_company_job| %> and used not(id: id)